# Using an x86 dll in a portable class library

Tags: c#, c++-cli, portable-class-library

### End Goal

I have an x86 dll built in c++.  I need to be able to use the dll from a portable class library.  This can be directly or indirectly, but I want to keep the entire application local on the users computer.

### What I have tried

I have designed a c++/cli wrapper to allow access to the dll.  I confirmed it works through an x86 console C# project.

- I tried using the wrapper directly from a portable class library but it would not allow the reference.
- I tried using the wrapper from a wcf library but the library is having problems with the cross platform dll.

I think I'm making this way too complicated but I am unfamiliar with a way to do what I want.  I can't rebuild the dll in 64-bit and do side by side loading - I only have the option of using the x86 dll.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: If you're talking about loading and using an x86 dll in an x64 process then the answer is no.  You can use COM however.

Comment: To add on to @EdS. comment, 

You'll want to look into using a COM DllSurrogate (which will use DllHost.exe to host your dll). Using this COM approach, you can make it so that your exe loads the dll in process when the exe is running in x86 mode, but talks to it out of process when your exe is running in x64 mode.

Comment: I don't know anything about COMs but I will research this and see if I can get it working. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to reference a C++ DLL from a Portable Class Library?  A C++ DLL isn't going to be usable from multiple platforms.  The point of PCLs is that they can run on more than one platform, but that means everything they reference needs to also be a PCL.

Probably what I'd recommend is to use the abstraction pattern, as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx).

Comment: I actually read that article prior to the post but went back and did it again for good measure. I rethought the design and decided a central server using webAPI to expose the DLL wouldn't hurt the overall solution (in my case I think it will actually help). Thank you for your input.